# Having problems with Android SDK Support Libraries

Tags: android, eclipse

So I am just starting to learn to program with Android. Everything works great (I'm using Eclipse as IDE by the way). I only had this problem. Every time I make a new project that I chose API 8 as the Minimum required SDK, and chose a theme (Holo Light with Dark Action Bar for example), Eclipse will **ALWAYS** import a **NEW COPY** of the Android Support Library v7 (appcompat). I know this is required for the ActionBar and Fragments on old devices (API 7 - 10). But what I don't get is why Eclipse has to import a new copy of the support library all the time (well I'm just starting to learn and I am thinking that the support libraries can be and is meant to be edited, I'm not sure).

So due to this, I made my own solution. I followed what is said [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) from the Android Developer website. I imported the support library to my Eclipse workspace by myself. Then I created a new project. So, Eclipse (once again) imported it's own appcompat-v7 support library. I deleted it and then on the Properties of my project, I replaced the deleted appcompat-v7 library with my own-imported v7 library I added earlier.

This could have been a solution, but I encountered some problems

- Eclipse added a new package in my **PROJECT_FOLDER/gen** named from the Support Library I imported manually, and as a result (which I don't understand why), it creates it's own R.java file (which causes a name collision-like effect). That is, when I mention something like this on my code, the R.java file that is searched was not the right R.java (but the duplicate R.java file)

  > **EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);** // this shows an error because the duplicate R.java file contains different fields from what the project's R.java file have
- Another thing, when I create a new Activity, many errors are popping on the Eclipse Console like

**[2014-04-08 14:53:49 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\ME\Documents\Android\Android Workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml:572: error: Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined**

- Additionally, the project will import **AGAIN** the appcompat-v7 library that it imported earlier (which I manually deleted) **AND** it will delete my R.java file **AND** will unassociate itself with the v7 library I manually created.

Is there a right way of doing this? Or the Support Library is really needed to be imported always? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem when accidentally recreating the MainActivity. As a result it imported a new reference to the Appcompat libraries.

You see these errors because there has been duplicate reference to the reference to the Appcompat libraries. Do not delete anything yet.

First thing you must do is remove the duplicate reference by right clicking on your project or press **Alt+Enter** to show the project properties window. Then click on Android tab and go to Library.

[image: Duplicate references to the Appcompat library]

On the list of referenced libraries, you will likely see more than one reference to the Appcompat library. Select one and click **Remove** then click Apply and OK.

You can then the unwanted MainActivity activity, its layout and menu XML files. But be sure to take extra care.

I hope this helps.

Comment: also check your dependency all library projects should also have same version of support library

Answer (score -2):

right click on project, go to properties, go to android, and then remove all app